# Join Query for 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I need to run a query which joins 3 tables and displays the unique set. I've 3 tables with the row below details:

```
Users : FName, LName, MobileNumber, STBNumber, CustID.
UserPay : STBNumber, CustID, PreviousDue, CurrentDue, ExpiryMonth, 
ExpiryYear.
Calendar: ExpiryMonth, ExpiryMonthName.
```

Now, the problem with the query is that it is displaying the columns STBNumber, CustID, Month and year twice.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   users 
       INNER JOIN userpay 
               ON users.stbnumber = userpay.stbnumber 
       INNER JOIN calendar 
               ON userpay.expirymonth = calendar.month;
```

The query should display all the unique columns across all the tables.

Comment: You can use distinct * while selecting the results

Answer (score 0):

So, I was working on a wrong join. Below is the query that solved my problem:

```
Select Users.FName, Users.LName, Users.MobileNumber, Users.STBNumber, Users.CustID, UserPay.PreviousDue, UserPay.CurrentDue, Calendar.ExpiryMonthName, UserPay.ExpiryYear from UserPay 
INNER JOIN Users ON Users.STBNumber=UserPay.STBNumber 
INNER JOIN Calendar ON UserPay.ExpiryMonth=Calendar.ExpiryMonth
```